# How to change value of bool in the same script attached to several GameObjects in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a calculator in Unity and faced with a problem.So I need to change bool value to write second number of my calculator.
My script attached to all the buttons(GameObjects) in the scene.
I need to change this value to `true` to write second number of calculator.

```
private bool input_second_num;    

public void Input(){

    if (calculate_label.text.Length < 15 && !input_second_num)   
    {
        calculate_label.text += btnNumber;
        first_num = long.Parse(calculate_label.text);
    }
    esle if (calculate_label.text.Length < 15 && input_second_num)
    {
        calculate_label.text += btnNumber;
        second_num = long.Parse(calculate_label.text);
    }
}

//Calls when clicking on action button
public void Action()
{
    input_second_num = true;
    calculate_label.text = " ";
}
```

At first `input_second_num` is `false` to write first number at first.When I'm changing `input_second_num` to `true` in another function clicking on action button and then trying to input second num, `input_second_num` is anyways false and I'm typing number for `first_number`.
Why is it so happening?

Comment: Are you changing `input_second_num` in the same instance of the class?

Comment: Yes, I have only 1 class

Comment: No, I didn't ask how many classes you have. I asked if you're changing `input_second_num` in the same _instance_ of your one class. Clearly [these two cars](https://preview.redd.it/n3k9t1l0hyt01.jpg?auto=webp&s=b95eb05e630ad3d4dd975368d7200ba949648ce2) are the same "class", but they are different instances and have different property values (e.g. the licence plate number is different between each instance of the car).

Comment: Oh, absolutely yes, there is private bool input_second_num

Comment: It seems likely to me that you're accessing different instances of the same class so making a change to one naturally doesn't reflect in the other. This is similar to how if I take a hammer to one of the cars, the other one won't also be damaged. You should investigate this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer with the code posted and my initial observations require more than will fit into a comment.

- You have posted two functions with the same signature `public void Input()`. I can't see how this code builds without issues; I must therefore assume that they are declared in different class types.
- This function is incorrect:

  ```
    public void Input()
    {
        else if (calculate_label.text.Length < 15 && input_second_num)
        {

            calculate_label.text += btnNumber;
            second_num = long.Parse(calculate_label.text);
            print("Second: " + second_num);

        }
    }
  ```

  You're starting an `if` block statement with an `else` - is there code missing?
- You state that you declared `input_second_num` as

  `private static input_second_num;`

  There is no data type assigned again I can't see how your code builds without issues.

Please revisit your question and show us more of your class code.

Comment: I forgot to add ```bool``` to ```private static bool input_second_num;```.You noted my ```else if``` block - it's a continuation of ```public void Input()```. Actually I've solved this problem, just wanted to edit my question